# json response deep node traverse print key value

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript function that will process a json response. The function would get the key value pair for each node. The json response node depth could be 2 to 5,6,7 deep. I tried function below, but it will only go 2 nodes deep. Is there a way to make a generic function like below that could process a variable depth of nodes in the json response?

```
function process(key,value) {
    Logger.log(key + " : "+value);
}

function traverse(o,func) {
    for (var i in o) {
        func.apply(this,[i,o[i]]);  
        if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
            //going on step down in the object tree!!
            traverse(o[i],func);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks to me like your code should recurse to all levels.

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/u7bo6tvx/4/

Comment: Don't  have response in front of me,but I know that I was getting [object] returned for some of the items. Thanks for comment, I will investigate further.

Comment: Your traversal function calls `func` on the element even if it's an object that it's going to traverse into further. When you concatenate an object into a string, you get `[Object object]`. If you don't want to do that, you should call `func.apply()` in the `else` block, not always.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with how deep it traverses. It still traverses into them after printing `[Object object]`.

Comment: Barmar, you are correct, all the nodes were being traversed. I misinterpreted the value output [Object object] as a node that was not being traversed. The [Object object] output was just the representation nodes at that level in the json response.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `traverse` function so it only calls the callback for leaves, not for intermediate nodes.

```
function traverse(o,func) {
    for (var i in o) {
        if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
            //going on step down in the object tree!!
            traverse(o[i],func);
        } else {
            func.apply(this,[i,o[i]]);  
    }
}
```

Comment: HI @Barmar, this is working well when i am trying to parse a deep nested one, what if i have to traverse through kind of json structures with same piece of code? my json structure sometimes contain arrays as well

Comment: Arrays are objects, so this will traverse them.